# Converting mysql query to sqlalchemy statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can I convert a query statement with mysql function into sqlalchemy:

Here is my query:

```
SELECT sDate FROM table where colA= "known"
and month(sDate) between 7 and 9
and sDate <> '0000-00-00'
and year(sDate) = 2018;
```

Currently I am using this script, but I am not sure how the month and year function converts to sqlalchemy script:

```
test = db.session.query(table).filter(table.colA== 'known', (func.date('year', table.sDate)) == '2018')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out already and got the solution:

```
test = db.session.query(table).filter(table.colA== 'known', (func.year(table.sDate)) == '2018'
        , (func.month(table.sDate)) >= '7', (func.month(table.sDate)) <= '9')
```

Comment: You could also use `func.month(...).between(7, 9)`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.between